# I have enabled ssh with pi zero w, but can't connect to the internet

Tags: vnc, internet, pi-zero-w

I have finish flashing Raspbian to my sd card and I edited the config.txt and cmdline.txt files and added an ssh file. Then I connected my pi to my computer via usb. I used putty to login and everything worked. I am trying to update and install everything for vnc to use the graphical desktop but I cannot do that without internet connection. I am having a really hard time connecting to the internet. Here is my ifconfig script.

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1389  bytes 131872 (128.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1389  bytes 131872 (128.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.82.163  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::a182:d5ed:28c2:3cee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 16:22:0c:e2:3f:43  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7603  bytes 776081 (757.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 12  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6502  bytes 1439006 (1.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:2c:e1:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: You need to **EDIT** your question and add details such as how you will connect to the internet (via a router, via a dedicated link).  Which device are you going to use for the connection, USB or wireless?  How have you set up the IP addresses (WLAN has no address) etc.  Have you followed the basic tutorials from raspberrypi.org ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your wifi details in wpa_supplicant.conf and drop it into your /boot folder. Boot, then restart.

In the wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU
network={
ssid="NetworkName"
psk="password"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
#fake network workaround for headless Raspberry Pi Zero
network={
ssid="fakessid"
psk="fakepass"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Alternatively you could use an open source tool I have developed for this exact problem.

[Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Wifi-Setup-Tool](https://github.com/RabbitGray/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Wifi-Setup-Tool)