# Password invalid after changing

Tags: ssh, password, raspbian-stretch

I have recently bought a raspberry pi, and I have installed raspbian on it. I decided to change the default password, but after that every time I tried to login to ssh, it said permission denied. I tryed to change the password again, but it said invalid password. The only way I could change the password was with sudo. After that it worked a while but the next day it said invalid password again! I have no idea why it keeps changing but I need it to stop. Any ideas?Also, I have enabled ssh through raspi-config

Comment: Did you change your password through SSH or with a physical keyboard attached?

Answer (score 1):

You might check if the keyboard settings are correct. The default keyboard setup is English (UK). If you are setting your password from a layout other than English (UK), you will actually set your password to something different than you want. For instance, if you think you're typing an @ (shift + 2), you're actually typing ".

Keyboard layout can be changed through raspi-config.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you connecting by WIFI? if so my [answer might help](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73097/73879) as you need to do some setup.
2. Have you ever been able to SSH into the pi before the password change?
   If you have a keyboard and monitor setup run the raspi-config

> sudo raspi-config

The first option you can set "User password" for example for the username "pi".

then under "Interfacing Options" enable SSH.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled ssh through raspi-config

Comment: Is your pi connected to your router? I think you have not setup your WIFI

Comment: updated my answer hope it helps.

Comment: im commenting on my pi! of course internet is set up

Comment: is your pi user account locked? what happens if you  passwd -u <your-username>

Comment: its not locked, the password works for a day or so.